# how to find section in didSelectRowAtIndexPath: method

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

Is it possible to find section of row where I am clicking in tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath method.

TIA

Comment: did you mean section or selection of particular index ?

Answer (score 10):

the indexPath parameter has section property accessible as following

```
[indexPath section];
```

OR

```
indexPath.section
```

Answer (score 2):

```
-(void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

 if(indexPath.section==0)
 {

    // 1st Section of the tableView.

   if(indexPath.row==0)
   {

      // 1st cell of the 1st section.

   }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
-(void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

   int section = [indexPath section];

}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
-(void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:
(NSIndexPath*)indexPath{
    int section = [indexPath section];
    NSLog(@"section %d",section);
}
```